# cp: missing destination file operand after

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

Im trying to do a full back up and copy over all files from one directory into another directory

```
    #!/bin/bash 

    #getting files from this directory
    PROJECTDIRECTORY=/../../Project3 

    #Copied to this directory 
    FILEBACKUPLOCATION= /../.../FMonday

    for FILENAME in $PROJECTDIRECTORY/*
    do
        cp $FILENAME $FILEBACKUPLOCATION
        done
```

But I keep getting this error

```
./fullbackup: line 6: /../../FMonday: Is a directory
cp: missing destination file operand after
```

Comment: Did you try without the space after the equal sign:  FILEBACKUPLOCATION=/../.../FMonday

Comment: Isn't /../../Project3 the same thing as /Project3? Also, ... is misleading. Anyway, add slash at the end of destination path.

Comment: It's also wise to double-quote the variables to avoid errors caused by issues such as space characters in the path.

Comment: I think it is calling for possible mistakes to name a directory `...` Note that `...` has a special meaning in some contexts (Novel NetWare, Windows 95, Golang). --- Using double quotes around variable references will also better show that the variable is either empty or nonexistent and it will better handle possible errors in such cases (typical example which can overwrite files: `cp path/* $nonexistent_var`).

Answer (score 8):

Variable assignments in bash scripts require no space between the variable name and value or (unless quoted) within the value. Since a space was present in the line `FILEBACKUPLOCATION= /../.../FMonday`, it attempted to execute `/../.../FMonday` as a command (which caused the first error) with `FILEBACKUPLOCATION` assigned to an empty string. The variable was then not assigned when the other command further down tried to use it (accounting for the second error).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you need is `FILEBACKUPLOCATION=/FMonday/`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just used used space and dot operator after the file name. It worked perfectly.

For Example, darthVader is a file name which is inside F drive. So, I used the command    "mv /f/darthVader . "

Answer (score 1):

Has you already found the variable needs to be `FILEBACKUPLOCATION=/location` with no space, also if possible try to make your script a little more portable by using something like:

```
FILEBACKUPLOCATION=$HOME/backup/FMonday
```

In this case, the location is relative to your user `$HOME` environment variable.

Going further, if you want to keep 2 files in sync probably you could do better with `rsync` one of the advantages is that it will only copy the files that don't exist or update the ones that have been changed.

You indeed could create an alias to copy/sync files on demand, for example:

```
alias cpr="rsync --delete --archive --numeric-ids --human-readable --no-compress --whole-file --verbose --info=progress2"
```

Then if you would like to sync contents of `/dir/foo` into `/dir/bar`, could simply do:

```
$ cpr /dir/foo/ /dir/bar/
```

Your script also could then be something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

ORIGIN=/path/to/foo/
DESTINATION=/path/to/bar/

rsync --delete \
--archive \
--numeric-ids \
--human-readable \
--no-compress \
--whole-file \
--verbose \
--info=progress2 \
$ORIGIN $DESTINATION
```

Notice that in this case the options `--no-compress` and `--whole-file` are used, mainly because the files will be copied locally, if this where a remote server options could be different, check this post ([The fastest remote directory rsync over ssh archival I can muster (40MB/s over 1gb NICs)](https://gist.github.com/KartikTalwar/4393116)