# pip 2 & 3 Syntax change

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pacman-package-manager

I use an arch-linux system and just installed pip via yaourt.
`yaurt -S pip`

Then I tried to install something via pip for python 3. But I get an error like this:

```
pip install requests
install: missing destination file operand after ‘requests’
Try 'install --help' for more information.
```

where

```
pip2 install requests
```

will just work.

What is the "missing destination file operand"? What am I supposed to pass?

Comment: Sounds like you are actually running the [`cp` command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324077/cp-missing-destination-file-operand-after). Which is run by the `install` command, not `pip`.

Comment: Are you sure you are actually using `pip` and not `install requests`?

Comment: `pip3 install requests` works just fine for me, so it looks like @MartijnPieters is just right (as usual:-).

Comment: err, I'm on an arch linux system and just installed pip via yaurt. After these comments, I reinstalled pip3 via pacman and now everything works... must be an internal problem from the yaourt package. THX

Comment: Might want to self-answer this briefly, so others can find it if necessary. Also might be good if you added more details (about you using Arch) to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments were right to assume that it has to work usually. There must be something wrong with the packed pip package for yaourt. I reinstalled python-pip via pacman and everything just works as intended.

Answer (score 2):

I see this is an old question, but for anyone who got here from a google search like me, the "pip" package in the AUR is not the python package manager! Install the package python-pip instead.

Answer (score 0):

I got this after a typo:

```
sudo -h pip3.6 install bpython
install: missing destination file operand after 'bpython'
Try 'install --help' for more information.
```

Fixing the parameter did the trick:

```
sudo -H pip3.6 install bpython
```